# writing a pandas dataframe(.csv) to local system or hdfs with spark in cluster mode

Tags: python, apache-spark

I'm trying to write pandas data frame to the local system or to hdfs with spark in cluster mode but it's throwing an error like

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: {hdfs_path/file_name.txt}
```

This is how I'm writing

```
df.to_csv("hdfs_path/file_name.txt", sep="|")
```

I am using python and the job is running through a shell script.

This works fine if I'm in local mode but doesn't in yarn-cluster mode.

Any support is welcome and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, i always convert the dataframe into a spark dataframe before creating a file on an Apache Spark filesystem :

```
df_sp = spark.createDataFrame(df_pd)
df_sp.coalesce(1).write.csv("my_file.csv", mode='overwrite', header = True)
```